# Angular2 + Firebase : How secure?

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have developed a collaborative notepadd app using Angular2 and Firebase. I am astound realising how beautiful are these two together but really afraid of moving this app to production! The nail biting fear of mine is the security. To me a pure javascript app seems vulnerable to security. Here is a sample of what I'm referring to.

```
<button *ngIf="userType == 'admin'" (click)="removeNote()">Remove</button>
```

And the function

```
userType: string = localStorage.get('userinfo').type;

removeNote(){
    if(this.usertype == 'admin'){
        this.af.database.list('/todo').remove('key');// end of story
    }
}
```

Is it not very easy to modify change the `type` in the localStorage? So anybody can hack the usertype and remove the `note` for ever? Why so insecure! Is there a way I could tighten the security on my side?

Comment: Use [database security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data).

Comment: Could you explain how do I restrict an unauthorised event? maybe a good article on Firebase Security would help

Comment: The documentation does a better job of explaining it than I could. Basically, you should leave your app as it is, but add database security rules so that if the app's code is changed, permission will still be denied at the database level.

Comment: Ill go through the docs

Comment: However my question is still unanswered. Anybody can gain access to a delete function by modifying localstorage data